# Input field help message based on connection parameter for my Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I want to generate a help directive whose text depends on a connection parameter. Trying to use a curly bracket expression doesn't work.

```json
{
  "type": "text",
  "label":"Relative URL",
  "name":"url",
  "help":"Enter a path relative to `{{connection.workspaceUrl}}`.",
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it directly the way you've tried it but you can use [RPC](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/app-structure/rpcs) for that.

Steps how to use RPC:

- Set **Mappable parameters** of your module to:

```json
"rpc://rpcGetInputParams"
```

- Create **RPC** with name *rpcGetInputParams*
- Set **Communication** of the RPC to:

```json
{
    "response": {
        "output": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label":"Relative URL",
                "name":"URL",
                "help":"Enter a path relative to `{{connection.workspaceUrl}}`.",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

(it is possible to call RPC without calling the 3rd party service. More info [here](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/structure-blocks/api/request-less-communication).)